# Chrome Browser Developer Tools Network Tooltip

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I used to be able to hover my mouse over the `Name` column in the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools, and see a tooltip with the URL of the resource downloaded. That seems to have gone now, so I need to show the URL column which takes up so much space when I don't need it 99% of the time. Is there any way to get the tooltip back?

Comment: Same issue here with Chromium – I think the tooltips disappeared within the last month or two. An imperfect workaround is to check "Use large request rows" in the Network tab settings.

Comment: I've created a related issue for Dev Tools https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1321037

Comment: It is available back on Chrome 102 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE CHROME 102: The network request hover tooltip is back on the Chrome 102 version.

It was removed on the Chrome 99 version. This has been reported and the project member was willing to hear from the users and they made a commit to bring it back, but not sure which upcoming version will have this commit included. As a web developer, I know how important is this small feature.

As of now Chrome 101 didn't have this issue fixed.

[image: Chrome issue report]